# Same SOQL Query taking a long time in a "VF page controller" VS in the "Developer Console"

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, soql

Simple query, taking 1 minute in the VF page controller, and less than 1 second when executed in the Developer Console.  There are more than 50,000 records that the query is searching through.  Why such a dramatic difference in the query run time?

```
String s = '123456';
List<Registration__c> regs = 
    [select id, name 
     from Registration__c 
     where name =: s or speical_number__c =: s limit 1];
```

Here are the excerpts from the debug logs:

*Developer Console:*

**12:22:39.063** (63557000)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[2]|Aggregations:0|select id, name from Registration__c where (name = :tmpVar1 or speical_number__c = :tmpVar2) limit 1

**12:22:39.263** (263582000)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[2]|Rows:0

*VF Page Controller:*

**12:17:08.148** (3148592000)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[633]|Aggregations:0|select id, name from Registration__c where (name = :tmpVar1 or speical_number__c = :tmpVar2) limit 1

**12:18:07.350** (62350264000)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[633]|Rows:0

Comment: No idea :/ As stupid as it sounds - in same environment? Any batch jobs / heavy usage kicking off in the background? Can you try indexing  the numeric column (mark it as external id)? Or even better - create a helper text field, use a workflow to fill it in with `Name + ' ' + TEXT(speical_number__c)` and try to use this field in the where clause?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this has to do with how VF/Apex batch-up replies.  Although, the limit 1 would seem to indicate that would not be the case.  But, just for kicks ... try this ...

```
String s = '123456';
List<Registration__c> regs = new List<Registration__c>();
for ( Registration__c reg : 
    [select id, name 
     from Registration__c 
     where name =: s or speical_number__c =: s 
     limit 1
    ] ) {
   regs.add(reg);
}
```

Is speical_number__c a good candidate for external id ?  I ask because setting that field to an external id will guarantee Salesforce.com will create an index for your field.  Without an index, the query would do a full table scan.